# Python strptime giving int instead of datetime object within dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe taken from an excel sheet, I'm trying to add some code to convert string dates to datetimes where they aren't automatically picked up as datetimes. There are 2 row entries of string '27/06/2019'

`df.loc[df['Start Date'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str)), 'Start Date'] =`

I have then tried the following:

`df.loc[df['Start Date'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str)), 'Start Date'].apply(lambda y: datetime.strptime(y, "%d/%m/%Y"))`

and the result I get is 1561593600000000000

When I try converting the datetime to date by putting a .date() at the end like this:

`df.loc[df['Start Date'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str)), 'Start Date'].apply(lambda y: datetime.strptime(y, "%d/%m/%Y").date())`

It works, but I only get a date object, not a datetime.

I've tried using datetime.combine with time.min and still the same problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think better here is use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'], dayfirst=True)
```

Or:

```
df['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'], format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

In your solution remove `.date()`:

```
mask = df['Start Date'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))
df.loc[mask, 'Start Date'].apply(lambda y: datetime.strptime(y, "%d/%m/%Y"))
```